# How to show the Workspaces ICON on the left-side Activity Bar of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to use the Workspaces Switcher extension in VS Code. Now it seems that the extension's features have been built into VS Code.

When I go to the workspaces settings I can see that the ICON for the "W" is set to show. But it does not appear in the left side activity bar. I also have no [known] way or switching between Workspaces.

Comment: "_Now it seems that the extension's features have been built into VS Code._" source? how so?

Comment: Because the extension now says: "This extension is enabled globally."

Comment: I just cannot get the "W" to appear on the activity bar. I use the "W" in the activity bar so when I click on it I can change my workspace. I can no longer do that and I cannot figure out how to switch workspaces.

Comment: there's a difference between [an extension being builtin to VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions) and just being enabled :P

Comment: What exactly is the difference? How do I get the ICON to appear on the activity bar or to find an easy and intuitive way to switch workspaces?

Comment: All I am looking for is the newer method to switch Workspaces.

Comment: you can open a list of _recently opened_ (not all) workspaces / files with the `File: Open Recent...` command in the command palette.